# How to store a number 51588284.25 in C++?

Tags: c++, decimal

How to store a number 51588284.25 in C/C++?

I failed using float or double , as:

```
float x = 51588284.25;
cout << x; //5.15883e+07
double y = 51588284.25;
cout << y; //5.15883e+07
```

Maybe float cannot express this number?

Comment: Use C `printf()` and format `"%.2f"` to format the value in a `double` with 2 decimal places.  C++ is selecting a format that is inappropriate for you.  You could adjust the format using manipulators, but you have to know which ones to use.  Using `float` won't work reliably; it can't represent the number accurately.

Comment: It's storing properly (at least for `double`). The default formatting settings just don't show floating point numbers that large. Read up on the [float format manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

Comment: Search your favorite C++ reference for "set_precision".